# Embarcadero RAD PHP XE2 - PageControls & Scrollbar in browser

Tags: php, radphp

I'm working with Embarcadero's RADPHP XE2 and a page I want to build has some text at the top (multiple lines) as a label, and below that a PageControl component - despite the page being set to be more than tall enough, when debugging and viewing in Internet Explorer there are no scrollbars and it chops the bottom of the page off.

Has anyone found a work around on this?

Answer (score 2):

I could not get scroll bars in my browser although the page is larger than the window.

Now fixed by adding this

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

to my css file.

To load my css file into the Page I put my tags into a text file including

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mainstyle.css" type="text/css">
```

then load the text file into the page my putting

```
$head = file_get_contents('defaulthead.txt');
echo $head;
```

into the OnShowHead event of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Les Kaye did not work for me.

For some reason, the script **/rpcl-bin/qooxdoo/framework/script/qx.js** does overwrite my stylesheet by inserting following CSS at runtime:

```
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

So what I simply did is using the **!important** rule. It is not clean, but the behavior of qx.js is not clean either. There should really be a Form property where the user can define if the page scrolls or not.

```
/* Overwrite the values which are enforced in /rpcl-bin/qooxdoo/framework/script/qx.js */
html    {overflow-x:scroll !important ; }
html    {overflow-y:scroll !important ; }
html    {overflow:scroll !important ; }
```